# is there a way to block access to Settings on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, password, settings

A family member (... with little fingers...) keeps accessing my phone (which is fine by me), but she also changes the Settings, plays with the Fingerprints and that causes a shockwave effect to all my logins to other apps.

Is there a way to block the access to Settings with a separate Passcode or otherwise? Maybe move it to a protected folder, if there is such thing?

Comment: A google search gave this: https://nerdschalk.com/6-ways-to-lock-an-app-on-iphone-and-ipad/

Comment: Changing the fingerprints is only possible after authentication. Does the little finger person know your code?

Comment: Accessing your phone should only be done under supervision, if at all.  As @nohillside says, why do they know your unlock code?